# OpenCV with Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I m a beginner in openCV . I m using version 2.1 exe application with visual C++ 2010.I tried a very simple program but the trouble is its getting built successfully only once. after that it shows 0 built succesfully; 0 failed ; 1 up to date. also i dint get any output ! Can somebody tell what does this mean and how to go about this problem ?

it is the basic code -

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <cv.h>                                     
#include <highgui.h>                                

int main(int argc,char* argv[])                    
{

    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("D:\photo\create.jpg");             


    cvNamedWindow("MyFirstWindow");                 
    cvShowImage("MyFirstWindow", img);              

    cvWaitKey(0);                                   
    cvReleaseImage(&img);                           
    cvDestroyWindow("MyFirstWindow");               
    return 0;
}
```

i have just installed it and im getting started with OpenCV!

Comment: Please show the code to enable users to give meaningful feedback.

Comment: you have to put the code to get where the problem is !

Comment: As far as I can see this is not an error. As it says: 0 failed and 1 is up to date. Try rebuilding - or make a change and try build again. VS wont compile if you haven't  made any changes...

Comment: #include <cv.h>                                                              #include <highgui.h>

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is

> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Since you haven't changed anything since you first built (i.e. it is up-to-date), VS doesn't try to build it again.

Choose *Rebuild* from the menu to force VS to rebuild your code, if you you really want to to.
If you change you code VS will build your code just using *Build*.

Comment: oh got it ! thanks ! one more thing ! when i run the program it says the exe file hasnt been found in tht !I cant figure out why is that happening !

Answer (score 1):

1. As already mentioned by others your program has no errors. It just has nothing new to compile.
2. When you are providing file path you are using '\' sign. In C++ this sign is reserved for all kinds of string parts that don't have symbolic representation. For example \n is 'enter' or \t is 'tab'. As a result it can't read path correctly and the image is not loaded. You should use either '\ \' or '/' instead. In general when you are reading image from the disk always verify that it is loaded properly before doing anything with it.
3. Don't use OpenCV 2.1. Really don't. Use its last version (2.4.7). When OpenCV went from version 1.0 to 2.0 (which was major concept change) it introduced a huge number of bugs. Part of them were fixed in 2.1 but a lot of those bugs remained. They were fixed gradually in latter versions.
4. C interface you are using is fading out and won't be supported in near future. Use C++ interface of OpenCV (Mat instead of IplImage*, imread instead of cvLoadImage, and so on).